# I am trying to create a multi label ML model using Adaptive Algorithm. I am facing an issue in preparing the data encoding and training set creation

Tags: python

Can any one help in fix error

```
  Message=Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [75, 3]
  Source=G:\Testing\Python\FirstConsolApp\MultiLabelAdaptedAlgorithm.py
  StackTrace:
  File "G:\Testing\Python\FirstConsolApp\MultiLabelAdaptedAlgorithm.py", line 19, in <module> (Current frame)
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42, shuffle=True)
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [75, 3]
```

in the below code

```
    import pandas as pd
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
    from skmultilearn.adapt import MLkNN
    from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score, f1_score, hamming_loss
    
    dataset = pd.read_csv("G:\work\ML\PythonEV1\Insurance Model\Data Files\sample_dataset.csv")
    dataset.fillna("", inplace=True)
    
    X = dataset[['ICD1', 'ICD2', 'ICD3', 'ICD4', 'CPT1', 'CPT2', 'CPT3', 'CPT4', 'CPT5', 'CPT6', 'CPT7', 'CPT8', 'CPT9', 'CPT10']]
    
    mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
    y = mlb.fit_transform(dataset[['ERR1', 'ERR2', 'ERR3']])
    
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42, shuffle=True)
```

using the below sample dataset

ICD1,ICD2,ICD3,ICD4,CPT1,CPT2,CPT3,CPT4,CPT5,CPT6,CPT7,CPT8,CPT9,CPT10,ERR1,ERR2,ERR3
K59.02,Z00.110,N81.6,,,,,,,,,,,,E202,E208,E211
B19.10,Z00.01,E55.9,,85025,80076,,,,,,,,,E211,,
Z00.00,Z00.01,,,81001,87088,,,,,,,,,E211,E106,
N83.201,Z00.121,,,76830,86304,,,,,,,,,E202,E209,E211
Z00.00,R10.83,,,82306,81001,,,,,,,,,E202,E209,
Z00.00,Z98.8,,,80061,85025,,,,,,,,,E205,E106,
M25.552,I25.10,O92.70,Z98.8,73521,76886,,,,,,,,,E202,E210,
K75.4,K21.0,B17.9,E03.9,85025,82947,,,,,,,,,E205,,
M06.00,E55.9,R79.89,,86038,85025,86140,85652,84460,84450,82977,82565,,,E106,,
R59.0,Z87.09,Z86.19,Z86.2,71045,94010,94729,82310,82164,,,,,,E211,,
Z00.00,Z38.66,Z00.01,,71045,80061,,,,,,,,,E202,E208,E106
Z23,Z42.1,,,90460,90461,,,,,,,,,E101,,
Z00.01,J30.9,Z82.49,Z83.42,80061,81001,,,,,,,,,E106,,
Z38.66,R30.0,R35.0,Z98.8,87660,,,,,,,,,,E202,E208,E102
Z00.00,Z98.8,,,80061,85025,,,,,,,,,E205,E206,
M25.552,I25.10,O92.70,Z98.8,73521,76886,,,,,,,,,E202,E210,
K75.4,K21.0,B17.9,E03.9,85025,82947,,,,,,,,,E205,,
N39.0,R30.0,R39.12,N39.41,87088,84153,,,,,,,,,,,
K76.9,K83.0,Z92.25,,85025,80076,,,,,,,,,E205,,
M19.041,M19.0,,,73120,85025,,,,,,,,,E205,,
N34.2,R10.83,,,87070,87660,,,,,,,,,E202,E209,E106
M19.041,,,,20604,,,,,,,,,,,,
Z34.92,Z3A.24,,,82951,82951,,,,,,,,,E211,E106,
Z23,,,,90460,90461,,,,,,,,,E101,,
N83.201,R10.83,,,86304,82105,,,,,,,,,E202,E209,E106
J98.59,D15.0,R05,,85025,82565,,,,,,,,,,,
H93.8X1,H61.21,,,69210,92553,,,,,,,,,,,
E04.1,E06.3,E06.0,R25.2,84439,84443,,,,,,,,,,,
K74.60,I10,E78.5,R11.0,96372,96372,,,,,,,,,E106,,
H65.93,R42,,,92553,92567,,,,,,,,,,,
M54.9,Z32.02,,,81025,,,,,,,,,,E103,,
R53.83,R63.5,R10.9,R14.0,85025,82947,,,,,,,,,,,
E03.9,R45.86,R63.5,R53.83,80061,85025,,,,,,,,,,,
R10.9,R19.4,B18.1,Z80.0,87517,87350,,,,,,,,,E106,,
Z00.00,,,,80061,81001,,,,,,,,,E106,,
Z23,Z98.8,Z98.8,,90460,,,,,,,,,,E205,E101,
K74.60,E11.40,I25.9,E78.5,84132,84520,,,,,,,,,,,
Z00.00,,,,76700,76700,,,,,,,,,E106,,
Z23,Z98.8,,,90460,83550,84466,,,,,,,,E205,E101,
R00.2,Z86.79,E78.5,I25.10,,,,,,,,,,,E211,,
I25.10,E78.5,R73.03,I10,83036,80061,84460,84450,,,,,,,E106,,
M75.41,M75.111,M65.811,Z01.818,85025,82565,80051,85610,93000,,,,,,E106,,
I25.10,N40.0,R73.03,I10,83036,80061,,,,,,,,,E106,,
S83.512D,Z98.890,,,73560,,,,,,,,,,E211,E106,
S83.511D,Z98.890,,,,,,,,,,,,,E211,,
E78.5,R74.0,,,80061,80076,,,,,,,,,E205,,
I37.0,Z95.2,E66.3,E78.5,80061,93306,83036,84295,84132,83735,82565,,,,E211,E106,
H10.32,,,,87070,,,,,,,,,,E106,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,E201,,
,,,,87635,,,,,,,,,,E201,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,E201,,
M75.42,,,,73221,,,,,,,,,,E106,,
R07.9,Z82.49,,,93350,,,,,,,,,,E211,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,E201,,
N92.6,N64.4,,,88142,83001,83002,84443,84702,76830,,,,,E106,,
E78.5,Z82.49,,,80061,,,,,,,,,,E211,,
Z48.01,K83.0,Z94.4,,97602,,,,,,,,,,E205,E201,
K62.89,K60.3,K64.2,S31.831A,82565,,,,,,,,,,E106,,
E55.9,R10.83,G47.00,,,,,,,,,,,,E202,E209,
Z23,Z98.8,,,90460,83550,84466,,,,,,,,E205,E101,
Z23,Z98.8,Z98.8,,90460,,,,,,,,,,E205,E101,
M54.9,Z32.02,,,81025,,,,,,,,,,E103,,
R10.9,R19.4,B18.1,Z80.0,87517,87350,,,,,,,,,E106,,
N83.201,R10.83,,,86304,82105,,,,,,,,,E202,E209,E106
Z23,,,,90460,90461,,,,,,,,,E101,,
Z34.92,Z3A.24,,,82951,82951,,,,,,,,,E211,E106,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,E201,,
R59.0,Z87.09,Z86.19,Z86.2,71045,94010,94729,82310,82164,,,,,,E211,,
I12.9,N18.2,M10.9,R73.02,82043,81001,,,,,,,,,E106,,
I12.9,M10.9,E78.2,R73.02,84295,84132,84520,82565,84460,84450,85025,83036,,,E106,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,E201,,
M81.0,E55.9,E58,,96372,,,,,,,,,,E106,,
D24.2,Z98.890,,,77065,,,,,,,,,,E211,,
O02.1,N96,Z3A.01,,76817,,,,,,,,,,E106,,
L30.9,,,,85025,84443,84439,82306,80061,82947,83036,,,,E106,,

Answer (score 0):

According to MultiLabelBinarizer [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.fit_transform), `y` parameter should be an iterable of iterables, where the inner iterables - are sets of labels for each row. Pandas DataFrame `dataset[['ERR1', 'ERR2', 'ERR3']]` is not that. I suggest transforming `y` a bit to be a Series of lists:

```
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
y = mlb.fit_transform(dataset[['ERR1', 'ERR2', 'ERR3']].apply(list, axis=1))

print("y:\n", y)
print("classes:\n", mlb.classes_)
```

Output:

```
y:
 [[0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
...
...

classes:
 ['' 'E101' 'E102' 'E103' 'E106' 'E201' 'E202' 'E205' 'E206' 'E208' 'E209'
 'E210' 'E211']
```

Comment: Yay, I'm glad! Please consider accepting this answer if it resolved your question :)